# How to extend a path?

Tags: python

I'm trying to install TA-Lib on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I've gotten to the point where I have to be able to do this :
`add /usr/local/lib to /etc/ld.so.conf as root then run /sbin/ldconfig (also as root).`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813279/python-wrapper-for-ta-lib-import-failure

I really don't know what it means.  I basically need to know what to type and where to type it.  Sorry for this noobish question.  I know how to enter terminal and how to `cd ls`, `cd ..`,and `cd folder`  Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Comment: Likely `ldconfig` already searches `/usr/local/lib`: try just running `sudo ldconfig`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Run ldconfig

As stated on the comment by steeldriver, execute `sudo ldconfig`. The system will become aware of any changes made.

### Just restart

You should not need to change anything.

By default `ld.so.conf` has `include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`. This commands makes the file include the contents of anyfile under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` that ends with `.conf`, which includes `include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf` which says:

```
# libc default configuration`
/usr/local/lib
```

Ergo I don't think you should need to add anything. Just restart your computer to let the software load any changes you have made. Although in most cases you just need to restart the specific service I am uncertain as to what you are changing here. A full system restart should do the trick though.

### If your computer is missing `libc.conf`

If by any chance `libc.conf` is missing then create a file `mylibc.conf` to remember that you added this yourself. This file will contain the command to add `/usr/local/lib`.

Open terminal and execute:

```
sudo echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mylibc.conf
```

By the contents of `ld.so.conf` this file should make the system be load `/usr/local/lib` automatically.